# Rotated matrix and rotated eigenvectors.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations

Let $R_\theta$ be a rotational matrix, 
my intuition (from experiences with quadratic forms) 
tells me that if $A$ has an eigenvector $v$,
then $R_\theta^T A R_\theta$ has an eigenvectors $R_\theta v$.

Is this true?
If so, how can I prove this?

Comment: Seems reasonable, have you tried diagonalizing the rotated matrix?

Comment: I am almost done with the proof, will post it soon, I hope. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite. The matrix $R_\theta^TAR_\theta$ has eigenvector $R^T_\theta v$, because $$R_\theta^TAR_\theta(R_\theta^Tv)=R^T_\theta A(Iv)=R^T_\theta Av=R^T_\theta(\lambda v)=\lambda (R^T_\theta v)$$
where I've used the fact that $R_\theta^TR_\theta=I$, because $R_\theta$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: This is almost exactly I am about to post! :)

Comment: on the other hand, the matrix $R_\theta AR_\theta^T$ has eigenvector $R_\theta v$, for the same reason...

Comment: Orthonormal is the more precise word here.

Comment: no, "orthonormal" refers to the *columns* of the matrix. the matrix itself is called "orthogonal": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix

Comment: I am rejecting the proposed edit that speaks of "left" and "right" eigenvectors: it is clear from the OP's post that the question was not written from an advanced enough perspective to distinguish these ideas, which would never show up in an undergraduate linear algebra course.

Answer (score 0):

Close.

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $v' = R_\theta^T v$ is an eigenvector of $R' =R_\theta^T A R_\theta$, with the same eigenvalue.

Proof:

$$
A v = \lambda v
$$
$$
R'v' = (R_\theta^T A R_\theta) (R_\theta^T v) = R_\theta^T A (R_\theta R_\theta^T) v
$$
$$
 = R_\theta^T A v = R_\theta^T \lambda v = \lambda (R_\theta^T v) = \lambda v'
$$

This proof relies on the equation: $R_\theta R_\theta^T = I$, which is true for rotations.

Comment: this is exactly the same answer as mine...

Comment: Sorry, you typed faster than me.  I didn't see your post until after I submitted mine.